# Equations and Solving them $X, Y, Z$

Tags: inequality

There is a Equation such as given below

$$[N\times X-(X+Y+Z)]^2 + [N\times Y-(X+Y+Z)]^2 + [N\times Z-(X+Y+Z)]^2 = N^3\times C^2$$

Here $X, Y, Z$ are real numbers. We are given N and C and we need to find a combination of $X, Y, Z$ that satisfies this equation if possible. Want any efficient method to get the combination.

Example:

$N=3$ and $C=0$, $X=3 , Y=3 , Z=3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single equation for three unknowns. There are many solutions. A simple way to get one of them is to additionally impose that $X=Y=Z$. Then your equation turns into
$$3(N-3)^2X^2=N^3C^2.$$
If $N\neq 3$ this equation has for example the solution
$$X=Y=Z=\frac{NC\sqrt{N/3}}{N-3}.$$